# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property role based

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, roles

1 user ==> many roles

1- role ==> many components

for this I have configured like

**userDao.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User_info")
public class UserDao {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name="password")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
       name="user_role",
       joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="userId")},
       inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="roleId")})
    private List<Role> roles;
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer roleId;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    private String roleName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List < UserDao > users;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
       name="role_component",
       joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="roleId")},
       inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="COMP_ID", referencedColumnName="compId")})
    private List<Component> components;
```

**component.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "component")
public class Component {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer compId;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    private String compName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "component")
    private List < Role > roles;
```

I am getting the following error, Please suggest the mistake

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an
>   unknown target entity property:
>   net.springboot.helloworldapp.bean.Role.component in
>   net.springboot.helloworldapp.bean.Component.roles     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:785)

Comment: You missed the error part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo. `component` should be `components`.

`@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "components") // <- should be components
    private List < Role > roles;`